# Multiple platform ID assignments to email address

Tags: sql, union, amazon-redshift

Interesting issue I'm facing.  I have 5 company tables that contain user information.  What I'd like to do have is an aggregate table of all the user id's associated to an email across the 5 companies.

i.e.  Company 1 (id, email), Company 2 (id, email), Company 3 (id, email).

Ideally, would like the table to read (email, c1_id, c2_id, c3_id).

Scratching my head on how to get all the distinct emails THEN company id's.

Comment: Can you provide some example data to illustrate wwhat you're working with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the data in the form you would prefer (email, c1_id, c2_id, c3_id, ...), you need to do a `LEFT JOIN` across all the tables on the email address. It needs to be a `LEFT JOIN` in case there is a Company table in which the email address does not appear. If you know that is not the case, then you can just use a `JOIN`.

**Update** since there can be emails in the other company databases that are not in company1 it is necessary to generate a list of email first and then `JOIN` that to the company tables:

```
SELECT e.email, c1.id AS c1_id, c2.id AS c2_id, c3.id AS c3_id, c4.id AS c4_id, c5.id AS c5_id
FROM (SELECT email FROM company1
      UNION
      SELECT email FROM company2
      UNION
      SELECT email FROM company3
      UNION
      SELECT email FROM company4
      UNION
      SELECT email FROM company5
      ) e
LEFT JOIN company1 c1 ON c1.email = e.email
LEFT JOIN company2 c2 ON c2.email = e.email
LEFT JOIN company3 c3 ON c3.email = e.email
LEFT JOIN company4 c4 ON c4.email = e.email
LEFT JOIN company5 c5 ON c5.email = e.email      
ORDER BY e.email
```

I created a small [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4cc9a5/3)

Comment: Does this `left join only` query not account for an email address that is unique to company2 and not in company1?  All companies have some unique emails, but there are also many emails that live in each company.

Comment: As is, it will only give you emails that are in company 1. Do you want it to return emails that are from all companies? That is doable (although a bit more complex...)

Comment: Yes.  That's the idea.  Creating more of "global" view of users across companies.   My thought is that I have to use some unions to grab all the unique emails to create an intermediate table THEN do left joins to grab the company id's.  That seems to get clunky with 15MM records

Answer (score 0):

`GROUP BY` using email then just use STRAGG(company_id)

`SELECT email, STRAGG(company_id) 
FROM table_name 
GROUP BY email`